# Power Raspberry Pi using two 3.7v Lipo batteries

Tags: pi-3, boot, power-supply, electronics, battery

I was having trouble while booting up my Raspberry Pi powered by LiPo batteries.

[image]

Ignore the components inside the blue circle
I am just connecting the batteries, the darlington transistor and the coverter.
The darlington transistor is used for switching when the power is connected
I am getting 5v from the dc-dc converter, but it is not properly running the rpi.
The rpi is running if i neglect the transistor, and connect just the batteries and the converter.
I think there is an initial current surge when rpi is connected which either the transistor or the converter is unable to cope up with. 
Any workaround for this?

Comment: Add a schema of your circuit.

Comment: Added the basic schematic

Comment: If that TP4056 module has a DW01A chip, be aware that it has current limiting. It will cut off load if too much current is drawn.

Comment: My problem arises without even connecting the TP4056 chip.

Answer (score 1):

If the red PWR led is on solid, no flickering, the power supply is probably okay.

> it just blinks its green led

This indicates an issue with the SD card.  Have you tried using a normal power supply?  Most likely it will do exactly the same thing.

The significance of the blinks is [summarised here](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern), although this may vary from one firmware version to another and as far as I am aware the Foundation does not publish anything official about it.  But the long and the short is there is something non-viable about your boot partition (anything wrong with the second, root partition would dealt with by the linux kernel, which does not blink anything but outputs to console).

Comment: The red PWR led is not on, but the raspi have had booted up before, even when the red LED was not on.

Comment: The red led indicates a solid power connection.  It is intended to flicker when undervolted (which often happens with a sudden increase in current draw if the source is insufficient).  If it is right off something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I've powered up a raspberry pi 2 and the official 7" screen with a 3.7V lipo battery and a [powerboost 1000C by adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-powerboost-1000c-load-share-usb-charge-boost/downloads) successfully without any power issues.

The [schematic is available](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/24638), so you might want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing a system with 6 li-po (2 in paralell with 3 in series) supplying a 100W UPS (from Aliexpress) regulating to 15V, and such 15V going into a LM2576 buck to 5V/2,5A to supply Pi 4 + 7" HDMI display, and it gives me 8h hours of battery power with no worries. The "rest" of the power from the 15V UPS goes into an isolated 9V/5A buck for my application (miliohmmeter), which gives me 50+ measurements (in 5A for 3 seconds each) capabilities. So far working all right.